# NUnit Generic test fixture not displaying when parameter implements generic interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, nunit

I have an interface defined like so:

```
public interface ITaskGenerator<T> where T : ITaskRequest
{
    int CreateTask(T request);
}
```

and an implementer:

```
public class OrderTaskGenerator : ITaskGenerator<OrderTaskRequest>
{
        public int CreateTask(OrderTaskRequest request)
        {
          ..
        }
}
```

What I want to do is make a generic test fixture using NUnit, that I can just specify all of the implementers of the `ITaskGenerator<ITaskRequest>` interface, to run the contract tests for all of them.

Luckily, NUnit has the ability to do that, with the Generic Test Fixture specified [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.5) . I've written the following (the `[TestFixture(typeof(OrderTaskGenerator))]` attribute is what's important for NUnit to pass through the correct type):

```
    [TestFixture(typeof(OrderTaskGenerator))]
    public class ITaskGeneratorContract<T> where T : ITaskGenerator<ITaskRequest>, new()
    {

        [Test]
        public void CreateTask_Returns_InvalidException_If_Task_ID_Is_Empty()
        {
          // Test goes here
        }
    }
```

However, this doesn't show up in Test explorer. If I make the interface non-generic it does.

So does anyone know a work around to this, or is there something else that I'm missing. I think it's because `ITaskGenerator` is a generic interface, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[TestFixture(typeof(OrderTaskGenerator), typeof(OrderTaskRequest))]
public class TaskGeneratorContractTest<T, TRequest> where T : ITaskGenerator<TRequest>, new() where TRequest : ITaskRequest
{
    private T _sut;

    public TaskGeneratorContractTest()
    {
        _sut = new T();
    }
    [Test]
    public void CreateTask_Returns_InvalidException_If_Task_ID_Is_Empty()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works a charm! Thanks a lot. I tried something similiar to this but I think I did `where T : ITaskGenerator<ITaskRequest>` instead of using the generic type.